# Devise : Unpermitted parameter: :name for Devise::SessionsController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using Devise and trying to log in with `:name` and `:password` fields. I can't log in and am getting the following error in rails console:

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for ::1 at 2020-11-04 20:53:24 +0600
Processing by Users::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"4481vpATudbSpQEOFHZJ0fLLf2ppgSnM4YrmsddOYGtQInJsgK+PBnjkp5avKL5p+iR/E7qqXGEBfPLPcm4Rww==", "user"=>{"name"=>"Abdullah Numan", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Log in"}
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 598)


Processing by Users::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"4481vpATudbSpQEOFHZJ0fLLf2ppgSnM4YrmsddOYGtQInJsgK+PBnjkp5avKL5p+iR/E7qqXGEBfPLPcm4Rww==", "user"=>{"name"=>"Abdullah Numan", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Log in"}
Unpermitted parameter: :name
```

I'm using `simple_form` and it looks like this:

`# sessions/new.html.erb`

```
<div class="column is-4">
        <h2 class="title is-3">Log In</h2>
        <%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: new_user_session_path) do |f| %>
          <%= f.error_notification %>
          <div class="field">
            <div class="control">
              <%= f.input :name,
                          required: true,
                          autofocus: true,
                          input_html: { autocomplete: "name", class: "input" },
                          wrapper: false,
                          label_html: { class: "label"} %>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="field">
            <div class="control">
              <%= f.input :password,
                          required: true,
                          input_html: { autocomplete: "current-password", class: "input" },
                          wrapper: false,
                          label_html: { class: "label"} %>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="field">
            <div class="control">
              <%= remember_me_checkbox(f) %>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="field">
            <div class="control">
              <%= f.button :submit, "Log in", class: "button is-primary" %>
            </div>
          </div>
        <% end %>
        <br>
        <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
        </div>
      </div>
```

My `SessionsController` looks like this:

`# sessions_controller.rb`

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  protected

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    user_path(resource)
  end
end
```

I tried using the guidelines in  [Devise Strong Parameters](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise#strong-parameters), but they don't work. How can I fix this?

Comment: Does this help https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address ?

Comment: @RockwellRice lol I came here to post this exact link. one up!